# C# String.Format with Nested Number Formatting

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a generic specification string generator that can format to any number of decimal places, i.e. "Temperature must be 20.5 C to 40.0 C", "Humidity must be 15 % to 85 %", "Gas inlet pressure must be 2.25 ATM to 2.75 ATM", etc.

Right now, I'm doing the following which works but I feel that it can be simplified.

```
public static string SpecToString(double minimum, double maximum, int digits)
{
    string numberFormatMin = "{0:f" + digits + "}";
    string numberFormatMax = "{1:f" + digits + "}";

    return String.Format(numberFormatMin + " to " + numberFormatMax, minimum, maximum);
}
```

Is there anyway for String.Format to "nest" parameters like the following?  As is, it throws an exception with input string not in the correct format.

```
public static string SpecToString2(double minimum, double maximum, int digits)
{
    return String.Format("{0:f{2}} to {1:f{2}}", minimum, maximum, digits);
}
```

Comment: Things should be as simple as possible. Not simpler.

Comment: You can to coerce a client to give rounded values.

Comment: The values are stored in a database at a reference unit of measure.  Then they can be converted, i.e. pressure in bar, PSI, ATM, Torr all of which would display with different decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `String.Format` calls if you find that "simpler"

```
var temp = string.Format("{{0:f{0}}} to {{1:f{0}}}", digits);
return string.Format(temp, minimum, maximum);
```